# How do I fix a git fsk error due to old invalid gitmodules file?

Tags: git

On our centralized git server we automatically run a periodic `git fsck`. On one of our repos it is failing with the following error:

```
$ git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
error: bad config line 43 in blob .gitmodules
error in blob 31e0c6cb966c309c4e6018fe280bbb9c40ca2902: gitmodulesParse: could not parse gitmodules blob
```

I tracked down the commit that contains this blob:

```
obj_name=31e0c6cb966c309c4e6018fe280bbb9c40ca2902 ; git log --all "$@" --pretty=format:'%T %h %s' | while read tree commit subject ; do     if git ls-tree -r $tree | grep -q "$obj_name" ; then         echo $commit "$subject";     fi; done
5adc29a fix develop
```

And then I tracked down the branches and tags that contain this commit.

I can see the invalid gitmodules, and it is indeed invalid due to a bad merge. I can see that the branch has another commit that fixes the bad merge. I can also see that the commit with the invalid gitmodules file is referenced by two tags.

I tried deleting the tags and running fsck again but that did not help.

I would like our automated git fsck to stop alerting and it seems the best way might be to correct the gitmodule in that specific commit. I only need to fix it on the server, I don't care if any clones or forks are missing the fix as the error happened over a year ago.

Can I do this safely, and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no: nothing in any commit can ever be changed.  There is one thing you can do, but it's a bit violent.

#### What you can do

The best you can do (besides ignoring the complaint) is to build a new and improved commit: one that's exactly *like* the original except for the bug.  But this is a new commit, with a new and different hash ID, not commit `5adc29a`.  So now you have to find all commits that have `5adc29a` as their parent(s), and make copies of *those* commits that have the new commit as the new-and-improved parent (and any original commits other than `5adc29a` as their other parent(s)).

Having changed both `5adc29a` and its immediate children, now you must find the children of the children of `5adc29a`.  They need to get the new and improved parents too.  Then you need to find *their* children, and so on.  This change, in effect, ripples down through the rest of history, all the way to all branch tips that descend from the bad—now replaced—commit.  Then it makes each branch-*name* point to the updated branch-*tip*.

There is a Git command that does all of this: `git filter-branch`.  Essentially, what `git filter-branch` does—or can do—is loop over *every* commit in the repository, applying some filter(s), and then committing the result.  If the result is bit-for-bit identical to the original, the result *is* the original and nothing changes.  If the result is different, though, that commit itself now has a new-and-improved substitute *and* every subsequent child commit will be re-parented as appropriate.  This of course changes the child, so that the child's copy is a new commit too, rippling down through the rest of history, all the way to all branch tips that descended from the original—now replaced—commit.

Hence "all" you need to do is run a `git filter-branch` command that replaces the bad commit with a new-and-improved one.  Run this over every commit and branch and tag name in your repository, and this:

```
root--c1--c2--...--bad--c1001--c1002--c1003   <-- master
                             \
                              c1004--c1005   <-- develop
```

becomes:

```
                    bad--c1001--c1002--c1003   [original master]
                   /   \
                  /     c1004--c1005   [original develop]
                 /
root--c1--c2--...--fixed--c1006--c1007--c1008   <-- master
                               \
                                c1009--c1010   <-- develop
```

Because every branch tip has been renumbered, and all the commits from them backwards to the bad one (now replaced with a renumbered commit) are also renumbered, **everyone with a clone of the bad repository must throw it away and switch to this new and improved one instead.**  Otherwise they still have the bad commit and all its descendants and they are very likely to re-introduce all that bad history you want gone.

#### Building the replacement commit

You *can* do this with a filter-branch filter.  That's the most direct way, but it's also hard to get right.  It's much easier to use `git replace`.

What `git replace` does is make replacement-lookaside commits.  These kinds of replacements aren't really *replacements*, they're just *additional* commits that you're telling your Git to use in place of the originals (and they won't help with this `git fsck` complaint since the originals *are* still there).  Essentially, if commit `5adc29a` is bad, you can make an improved-on commit that has the same *parent*(s) as `5adc29a` but good contents.  Then you tell your Git: *Whenever you're about to look at `5adc29a`, look at this other commit instead.*

A few Git commands, including `git gc` and `git fsck`, deliberately *don't* obey replacements.  All Git commands can be told not to obey it, to see what's really there.  But most, including `git filter-branch` itself, obey the replacements by default.

What this means is that you can build a replacement, verify that everything looks good, then just run a `git filter-branch` with `--all` (and appropriate `--tag-name-filter` if needed) but no other filters, that, in effect, cements the replacement in place.  Then you delete all the `refs/original/` names that `git filter-branch` uses as seat-belts-and-airbags in case the filtering goes wrong, and now you have a repository where the bad objects no longer appear at all (and `git gc` will remove them for real eventually).

This repository is no longer compatible with the bad one—or rather, it's all *too* compatible, and having it meet the bad one will cause the bad commit to come right back, along with all the children that you replaced with the filter-branch step.  It's up to you to decide whether the pain of such a [flag day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_day_(computing)) is worth the benefit.